# WordPress Mail SMTP needs verification from Google

Tags: wordpress, oauth, smtp, gmail

I installed the OAUTH-based SMTP plugin from WordPress to send and receive emails on my website using Gmail, but Google says it needs verification. According to Google these apps don't need verification; so I don't know what's happening. Can I bypass the verification, and if not how do I request the verification?

When I connect to Google to get authorization to finish configuring the mailer settings and save the Client ID and Client Secret, Google tells me the developer, me, needs to verify this app with Google.

Comment: single user apps dont need verification.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's true, but it's asking for verification at any rate. How do you even verify it?

Comment: Where is it asking for verification?  On the consent screen if so ignore it its just you using it.

Comment: I need to authorize the Gmail mailer. When I attempt to, Google gives me the message "Google hasn’t verified this app
The app is requesting access to sensitive info in your Google Account. Until the developer verifies this app with Google, you shouldn't use it.
If you’re the developer, submit a verification request to remove this screen."

Comment: yeah ignore that its just you using grant it access and your good to go